# method to type Cangjie secondary signs?

Tags: traditional-characters

Is there a method available to type all the secondary signs for Cangjie as listed in these two charts:
http://www.pascal-man.com/navigation/faq-java-browser/image-cangjie/cangjie-1.gif

http://www.pascal-man.com/navigation/faq-java-browser/image-cangjie/cangjie-key.jpg

I did a search and found this thread but I am still unsure of how to type these specific signs.
[Typing Chinese radicals?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/5581/typing-chinese-radicals)

Comment: The secondary signs are listed in the two image links posted above.

Comment: Yes, the blue text is the secondary signs and the red text is the primary signs. Please excuse me if my original post was unclear.

Comment: You probably have to split the signs as normal Chinese letters using ordinary Cangjie methods. For example to type 亻, it can actually be split to 丿 and 丨, which means "竹中". And of course to type those 1-stroke signs like 丿, simply type "竹".

Comment: @hinen 冖刂 can be typed at http://chinesecj.com/ime/cj5.php (cutt.ly/oiar) but I'm not sure about other auxiliary shapes.

Answer (score 3):

They are auxiliary glyphs (輔助字形).

For example,

[image]

According to the [wikibooks](https://zh.wikibooks.org/wiki/%E5%80%89%E9%A0%A1%E8%BC%B8%E5%85%A5%E6%B3%95/%E8%BC%94%E5%8A%A9%E5%AD%97%E5%BD%A2) the rules to input them are as follows.

> 倉頡字母單獨成字時，取一碼即可。
>   The basic glyph (radical) that forms a word just takes ONE code.
>   For example, 日 is input with the key "A".
>
> 輔助字形單獨成字時，則須依拆碼規則拆碼。
>   An auxiliary glyph that forms a word should be decomposed according to the rules of decomposition.
>   For example, ⺜ is split into 冂(B), 一(M) and 一(M).

However, there are two more requirements in order to input them.

1. It is coded in Unicode.
   (otherwise you have to make your own fonts)
2. The input method engine you use includes it.
   (or you can make your own table)

For example,

⺜, ⺝ and 冃 are encoded and can be input with the keys BMM.

[image] must be decomposed into 囗(W) and 丨(L).
Since it is not encoded, it cannot be input directly.

Answer (score 0):

As @hinen said, they are auxiliary glyphs.

To type some auxiliary glyphs, you can try 輸入法整合器(https://support.microsoft.com/zh-tw/help/2838160) and see how to type them.

Others may use unicode to type them.